# Paging not working in GridView when ajax control is removed

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a grid view in my aspx page. I have enabled paging also.

Paging is working fine when an ajax control is in page, but when I removed the ajax control paging is not working anymore. ie, on clicking page number 2 grid becomes empty.

What could be the possible reason? Please suggest a solution.

**code**

```
<asp:GridView ID="SitesGrid" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" DataSourceID="SitesDataMgr" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" CellPadding="3"   CellSpacing="3" OnRowDataBound="viewSite_RowDataBound" class="tbl_blck gridtable clearfix" PageSize="4" EmptyDataText="No rows found">
    <Columns>
         <asp:TemplateField Visible="false">                
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="clientID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ID") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>                
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name"  HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" SortExpression="ClientName">                
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="clientLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ClientName") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>                
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" SortExpression="SiteStatus">                
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="siteLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SiteStatus") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>                
        </asp:TemplateField>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Details" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" > 
         <ItemTemplate>                                 
                 <asp:LinkButton ID="viewSite" runat="server" OnClick="viewSite_click"  CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit"
                    Text="View"></asp:LinkButton> 
                    </ItemTemplate>                               
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>   
</asp:GridView>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="SitesDataMgr" runat="server" ConvertNullToDBNull="True" OldValuesParameterFormatString="{0}" SelectMethod="GetAllSitesByUser" FilterExpression="ClientName LIKE '%{0}%'"  TypeName="Creation.DataMgr"> 
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter  Name="createdUserID" Type="String" SessionField="strUserName" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <FilterParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="ClientName" ControlID="txtSearch" PropertyName="Text" />
    </FilterParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Comment: please put your code here]

Comment: @KillerR i have now pasted code in my question

Comment: the code u provided is not clear, after seeing all from your question one would want to know: what ajax control u r talking about ? what is code for gridview's page index changed event, what is the code in page load event of the page.

Comment: I have put TextBoxWatermarkExtender ajax control for a text box.Then the paging is working fine

Comment: void SitesGrid_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            SitesGrid.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            SitesGrid.DataBind();
        }

Comment: @UsmanWaheed i have pasted code above

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have not added the `SelectCount` method to your ObjectDataSource.
This is required for the ObjectDatasource to correctly page your data.

Your select method needs the int parameters `maximumRows` and `startRowIndex`  This is the default parameter names required for paging. if you do have them in. Please use them to filter your data.